# ActiveStorage issues not uploading or not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

So im trying to add the ability for users  (devise) to upload images to a listing.

**First off:** I have a listings controller and the listings params I have it defined

```
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, images: [])
end
```

Next: In the listing model I have:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

And finally, I have the form and the index set up with

```
= simple_form_for @listing do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.file_field :images, multiple: true
  = f.text_area :description
  = f.button :submit
```

```
.listings.has-gutters
  - @listings.each do |listing|
    .box
      - @listings.images.each do |image|
        = image_tag(@listings.images[image])
      .listing-info
        %h3= link_to listing.title, listing_path(listing)
        %p= listing.description
        %p= listing.user.firstname
```

With all this, I would assume it would work but when uploading the images it gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError in Listings#index
Showing /Users/timbogdanov/Desktop/vend/app/views/listings/index.html.haml where line #5 raised:

undefined method `images' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f8ef1208578>
Extracted source (around line #5):

  - @listings.each do |listing|
    .box
      - @listings.images.each do |image|
        = image_tag(@listings.images[image])
      .listing-info
        %h3= link_to listing.title, listing_path(listing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was a dumb mistake. 
looks like in my view file for index i used the variables @listings instead of my for each look just listing

Corected:

```
.listings.has-gutters
  - @listings.each do |listing|
    .box
      - if listing.images.attached?
        - listing.images.each do |image|
          = image_tag(image)
      .listing-info
        %h3= link_to listing.title, listing_path(listing)
        %p= listing.description
        %p= listing.user.firstname
```